# How to close console in Chrome using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I know how to check whether or not the console is open, but is there a way to close the console once you've detected that it's open?

```js
window.requestFrame = (function() {
  return window.requestAnimationFrame || (window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || (window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || (window.msRequestAnimationFrame || (window.oRequestAnimationFrame || function(c) {
    window.setTimeout(c, 50);
  }))));
})();
var test = {
  st: false,
  el: document.createElement("img"),
  rn: function() {
    test.st = false;
    console.log(test.el);
    console.clear();
    document.getElementById("testText").innerHTML = "The JavaScript console is " + ((test.st === true) ? "open" : "closed") + ".";
    window.requestFrame(test.rn);
  }
};
(test.el).__defineGetter__("id", function() {
  test.st = true;
});
test.rn();
```

```html
<p id="testText"></p>
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.  You may be able to disable user scripts though: https://davidwalsh.name/disable-console

Comment: I've seen that method, the article you linked to is actually outdated and you can bypass that method without too much trouble.

Comment: Ah, good to know. : )